# Rails - lookup record based on attribute besides id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with Rails v4, and I have a controller that was generated via scaffolding.  I want the route for the update action to be based on the `machine_name` attribute of the model that I've defined, rather than the ID.  However, in routes.rb the routes are being generated for the modeal via resources.

So here are the default routes for the resource:

```
                rooms GET    /rooms(.:format)                           rooms#index
                      POST   /rooms(.:format)                           rooms#create
             new_room GET    /rooms/new(.:format)                       rooms#new
            edit_room GET    /rooms/:id/edit(.:format)                  rooms#edit
                 room GET    /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#show
                      PATCH  /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#update
                      PUT    /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#update
                      DELETE /rooms/:id(.:format)                       rooms#destroy
```

So for a PATCH/PUT request, the update method will fire when I submit, for example, /rooms/folsom_prison.  Rails will then look at folsom_prison as an ID and try to match the parameter to a value in the `id` column, rather than the `machine_name` column.  How do I get Rails to change the column it is looking the record up on?

Current code I'm working with:

```
  # PATCH/PUT /rooms/1
  # PATCH/PUT /rooms/1.json
  def update
    @room = Room.find_by_machine_name(params[:id])
    room_params.delete(:id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if Room.update(@room.id,room_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @room, notice: 'Room was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Resulting error message from the log:

```
Started PATCH "/rooms/folsom_prison" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-13 16:28:53 -0400
  Room Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "folsom_prison"]]

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Room with id=folsom_prison):
  app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb:69:in `set_room'
```

...and the cURL request I'm making to test against:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X PATCH -d "room[booked]=1" localhost:3000/rooms/folsom_prison
```

Comment: How about `if @room.update_attributes(room_params) ...`?

Comment: That results in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `find_by_*` helpers in Rails 4. This is what you want to do

```
Room.where(machine_name: params[:id])
```

To get your routes to work correctly, you will want to override `to_param` in your `Room` model

```
require "uri"

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def to_param
    URI.escape(machine_name)
  end
end
```

Say you have a room instance

```
@room = Room.new machine_name: "foo"
```

When you create a link, everything will be wonderful!

```
<%= link_to @room.machine_name, @room %>
#=> <a href="/rooms/foo">foo</a>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the specifics.

Comment: Question regarding the deprecation of find_by_* methods.  Reading about it on the Rails edgeguides page, it seems that not all find_by methods are deprecated http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html... perhaps I'm misreading?

Comment: @LesterPeabody I never said they were deprecated, but they're certainly not necessary anymore. I would expect them to be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for friendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: This looks nifty, I will look into integrating this later on.

Answer (score 0):

@naomik is right about the depricated `find_by_*` methods, however, the've been replaced by `find_by` method, not `where`.

```
Room.find_by(machine_name: params[:id])
```

This will find 1 record and return it, but `where` will find all records that match this, and always return them in an array, even if there's only one.